# Is there a way to toggle an annotation based on the active profile in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In our project, we have database definition like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"com.sap.s4hc.fnd.circ::PRECHECK_ITEM\"")
@Cacheable(false)
public class PrecheckItem extends AdminField implements Comparable<PrecheckItem>, Serializable
```

However, as the database naming schema follows SAP HANA's convention (`namespace::table_name`), it doesn't play nicely with Spring Boot/Hibernate. The database in production environment is created with means other than JPA/Hibernate.

The current implementation works fine on cloud, but in local development environment, where H2 database is used, I believe Hibernate doesn't support the current naming strategy. Hence a `Table "com.sap.s4hc.fnd.circ::PRECHECK_ITEM" not found;` is always thrown.

Apparently, I can have two different set of entity classes ready to mitigate this issue as `PrecheckItemLocal` and `PrecheckItemCloud`, where I use profiles to activate them respectively, but it would be really nice if I can simply:

```
@Entity
@Profile ("cloud") {@Table(name = "\"com.sap.s4hc.fnd.circ::PRECHECK_ITEM\"")}
@Cacheable(false)
public class PrecheckItem extends AdminField implements Comparable<PrecheckItem>, Serializable
```

Is there an implementation like this available?

Comment: I think you can try create implementation of `PhysicalNamingStrategy` for `Profile("cloud")`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-hibernate-naming-strategy

Answer (score 0):

unfortunetly so far there is no way to do that in the way you would like to. So, the only way is the one you mentioned to have two different sets of entities.